# this.navCtrl.setRoot is not working in Cordova InAppBrowser web-view IONIC 2/3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, inappbrowser

i am implementing **PayYouMoney** payment gateway in my ionic app, for this I have to call web view pages for payment transaction, i want application back in my ionic **thankyou** and **failed** pages from webview as per **web-view** url conditions. below is my code:

```
var url = 'https://www.sansuiscales.com/web/payment.php';
    var target = '_blank';
    var options = "location = yes"
    var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);

 ref.addEventListener('loadstart', loadstartCallback);
 ref.addEventListener('loadstop', loadstopCallback);


function loadstopCallback(event) {
   if(event.url == "https://www.myDomainname.com/web/success.php") {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(thankyou); // not working
   // ref.close();
    }

   if(event.url == "https://www.myDomainname.com/web/failour.php") {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(failed); // not working
   // ref.close();
    }
}


function loadstartCallback(event) {
       alert(event.url);
    }
```

why **this.navCtrl.setRoot()** is not working , how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just compile it and run it on the phone. It won't work on browser but will do on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

`this.navCtrl.setRoot()` is called inside a JavaScript function, **this** refers to a context where **navCtrl** is not available. You need to bind this to the correct context (using the old way `self = this`) or consider using arrow functions instead

```
var loadstopCallback = (event) => {
   if(event.url == "https://www.myDomainname.com/web/success.php") {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(thankyou); // not working
   // ref.close();
    }

   if(event.url == "https://www.myDomainname.com/web/failour.php") {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(failed); // not working
   // ref.close();
    }
}
```

Read more about arrow functions https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/